# Docker swarm and volumes

Tags: docker, cassandra, docker-swarm

Considering Docker 1.12. I understand that volumes are not per say portable across the swarm and that solutions like Flocker would be better for larger clusters.

Nevertheless, is the option I describe below acceptable for my setup?

**Setup**
 A swarm with 3 nodes runnin Docker 1.12.latest from the experimental branch.

**Goal**
 Run a nice but small Cassandra cluster.

**Problem**
 I want to decouple the *stateful* part of the service (the data volume) from the *stateless* Cassandra daemons.

**Proposed solution**
 Create a named volume manually on each node with the same name on each node.
 Use `docker service create --name cassandra --replicas 3 --mount type=volume,source=cassandra_data,target=/usr/var/cassandra`

My understanding is that one replica of the Cassandra will be run and every node, each one referring a local named volume with the same name.

Would this work?
Do I need to specify a constraint to make sure there is at max 1 replica per node of the swarm?

**Edit**: reading the doc, it seems I should use `--mode=global` instead of `replicas=3` to run exactly 1 replica per node of the swarm. Which makes a lot of sense...

Answer (score 0):

Yes this does work, and using the global flag will be a better option to prevent any conflicts. I have run a similar model to this with MongoDB as a test and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As of the 19.03 release, there is now an option to limit the number of replicas per node to avoid multiple replicas accessing the same volume:

```
$ docker service create --help

Usage:  docker service create [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]

Create a new service

Options:
...
      --replicas-max-per-node uint         Maximum number of tasks per node (default 0 = unlimited)
```

With this added to the `service create` command, the next step will be adding a placement preference in the compose file to support `docker stack deploy`.